# Plotdevice, turn json value into variable

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
size(297,420)
weather = read("january_2016.json", dict=adict)
print "(in january 2016 the min temperature was %i)" % weather.MaxTemperature.min

r = "%i" %weather.MaxTemperature.min

nofill()
stroke(.1)

print r
oval(10,10,r,r)
```

but I have two problems here:
1. when I want to use oval(10,10,`r,r`) I get the following error:

```
DeviceError: Invalid coordinates (looking for ['Point', 'Size'], got ['Point', 'str', 'str'])
```

2. how can I center the anchor of an oval
Who can help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oval()` needs 4 numbers

```
oval(x, y, width, height, plot=True, **style)
```

But you have this line

```
r = "%i" % weather.MaxTemperature.min
```

it results in `r` being a `str` (a string type, not a numeric type)

Why not try `r = weather.MaxTemperature.min` directly as it's probably a number

```
r = weather.MaxTemperature.min
# or if that value isn't numeric, try converting it to a float
# r = float(r)

...
oval(10, 10, r, r)
```